# SQL INSERT/SELECT using WITH clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert-select

I'm trying to make a copy from two tables based on a list of IDs, those IDs are retrieved from an initial table, then those IDs are used into an **INSERT SELECT** statement, also the created IDs from the previous **INSERT** must be inserted into a third table:

```
BEGIN;

WITH dog_tmp AS (SELECT id FROM dog WHERE toy_id = '12345'),
meal_tmp as (INSERT INTO meal (id, dog_id, date_created, type)
    SELECT public.uuid_generate_v4(), dt.id, m.date_created, m.type
    FROM meal AS m
    JOIN dog_tmp dt ON dt.id = m.dog_id RETURNING m.id AS meal_uuid)

INSERT INTO dog_diet (id, meal_id, date_created)
SELECT public.uuid_generate_v4(), mt.meal_uuid, dd.date_created
FROM meal_tmp mt
         JOIN dog_diet dd ON dd.thread_id = mt.meal_uuid;

COMMIT;
```

I'm getting this error: ***[42P01] ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "m"***

Thanks in advance for your hints about this, or if possible another approach.

Comment: `FROM meal AS m` should simply be `FROM meal m` or `RETURNING m.id` might simply need to be `RETURNING id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer: change `RETURNING m.id AS meal_uuid` to `RETURNING id AS meal_uuid` ([db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/2170)).

So the full statement at issue is:

```sql
INSERT INTO meal (id, dog_id, date_created, type)
    SELECT public.uuid_generate_v4(), dt.id, m.date_created, m.type
    FROM meal AS m
    JOIN dog_tmp dt ON dt.id = m.dog_id 
RETURNING m.id AS meal_uuid
```

Within the select you set `m` as an alias for `meal` but the scope of this is the `SELECT` query (so `m` is not defined within the outer `insert` statement).